# Rails: How to render path to namespaced file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, namespaces, associations

I'm trying to learn how to use namespaced folders in my Rails 5 app.

I have models for Organisation and Package_ips. Package is the name of a folder that I use to collect different types of assets. Ip is one of those nested assets.

The associations are:

Organisation

```
has_many :ips, as: :ipable, class_name: Package::Ip
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ips,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Package::Ip

```
belongs_to :ipable, :polymorphic => true, optional: true, inverse_of: :ip
```

My routes.rb file has:

```
namespace :package do
    resources :ips
end
```

In my organisation show, I'm trying to render a link to the package/ips/show.html.erb with:

```
<%= link_to package_ips_path(@organisation) do %>
```

I have also tried the following (although I think its wrong):

```
<%= link_to package_ip_path(@organisation) do %>
```

In both cases, I get an error that says:

```
uninitialized constant Package::IpsController
```

I don't understand this error because when I go into my rails console, I can see that there is an instance of Package::Ips.

```
o = Organisation.first
o.ips
  Package::Ip Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "package_ips".* FROM "package_ips" WHERE "package_ips"."ipable_id" = $1 AND "package_ips"."ipable_type" = $2  [["ipable_id", 1], ["ipable_type", "Organisation"]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Package::Ip id: 1, status: "Offered", classification: 0, identifier: "dasfdsfasd", description: nil, conditions: "asdfdsfsd", ipable_id: 1, ipable_type: "Organisation", created_at: "2016-11-02 21:05:36", updated_at: "2016-11-02 21:05:36", title: "test ip resource">]>
```

My rake routes | grep ip shows:

```
package_ip GET      /package/ips/:id(.:format)                                            package/ips#show
```

How can I link to the Ip show view from the organisation show page?

UPDATE

I think this problem might have something to do with there being many ip instances.

I tried making a view for index.html.erb and tried to render the link again.

This time the error says:

```
uninitialized constant Package::IpsController::Ip
```

There is an extra "::Ip" on the end of the error message.

I still don't understand the problem, but the index action of the Package::IpsController is highlighted in the error message. That action has:

```
 def index
    @ips = Ip.all
    # authorize @ips
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes around your class name.  It should look like this:

```
has_many :ips, as: :ipable, class_name: 'Package::Ip'
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. I tried that - but it doesnt change the error.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the error.  The error is not about your model, but rather the controller. Do you have `app/controllers/package/ips_controller.rb` defined?

Comment: Yes, it begins with this line: class Package::IpsController < ApplicationController

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out I have to write the index action like so:

```
@ips = Package::Ip.all
```